# Can't configure angular routing

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm learning angular.js     and has done some 'Hello world' app. It's work like i planned, all,  except routing. Please help me find mistakes in my code (i think it's in app.js)

```
    angular.module('usercat', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', 
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/messages', {
          templateUrl: '/messages.html',
          controller: 'UserListCtrl'}).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/messages'
        });
  }]);
```

[Here is my demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHeWjSgkya52B3JfDdOQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ng-view tag in index.html. This is where your messages will be shown. So just add the following and it should work:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```